# save element of dynamic combo box

Tags: grails

I am a beginner in Grails, in my application I was created a dynamic combo box (it's not an attribute of my domain class)

In my view

```
function addCombo() {
var textb = document.getElementById("txtCombo");
var combo = document.getElementById("combo");

var option = document.createElement("option");
option.text = textb.value;
option.value = textb.value;
try {
    combo.add(option, null); //Standard
}catch(error) {
    combo.add(option); // IE only
}
textb.value = "";
}

function AfficherCombo()
{
    var myCombo = document.getElementById('Combo');
    var l = myCombo.options.length;
    for (var i=0; i < l; i++){
            var val =  myCombo.options[i].value;
            if ( val== dep || val == dtdep){
                myCombo.options[i].selected=true;
                break;
            }
    }
}
```

Code HTML:

```
<g:form action="save">
    <input type="text" name="txtCombo" id="txtCombo"/>
    <input type="button" value="ajouter" onclick="addCombo()"/>
    <br/><br/>
    <select name="combo" id="combo" ></select>
 </g:form>
```

I use my sql database.

How can I save the element of the combo box to retreive them in other time?

Comment: Could you either: (a) Provide the Domain object you are utilizing and want to save -or- (b) Let us know what data from your form you want to be persisted?

Answer (score 0):

First, HTML does not have a "Combo Box".  HTML has a SELECT element.  Secondly, if you're asking how to save the selected value of the SELECT element in the database, you would have to resort to JDBC since the property is not part of any of your Grails Domain classes.

If you don't need to store it in the database, and you just need to reference it later, look into the different Java EE application scopes like session, request, etc.  Find the most appropriate one that suits your needs.